# Comunicacion por Bus Vue CLi

Tags: vue.js, electron, cli

hola tengo este codigo con vue cli y no me esta actualizando los datos del segundo componente estoy usando un proyecto echo en electron-vue/vuetify

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.css'

import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

export const clientBus = new Vue({
  methods: {
    editClient: function (editable, client) {
      console.log(editable)
      this.$emit('editable', {editable, client})
    }
  }
})

Vue.use(Vuetify)
if (!process.env.IS_WEB) Vue.use(require('vue-electron'))
Vue.http = Vue.prototype.$http = axios
Vue.config.productionTip = false
/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  components: {App},
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>'
}).$mount('#app')
```

componente 1

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid grid-list-xl text-xs-center>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs10 offset-xs1>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title primary-title dark class="red lighten-1 pointer" @click="show = !show">
            <div>
              <div class="headline white--text pointer"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Filtro de busqueda</div>
            </div>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-icon icon class="white--text pointer">{{ show ? 'fa-chevron-up' : 'fa-chevron-down' }}</v-icon>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-slide-y-transition>
            <v-card-text v-show="show">
              <v-form v-model="valid">
                <v-layout row wrap>
                  <v-flex xs12 md3>
                    <v-text-field
                      label="Nombre"
                      v-model="filter.name"
                      prepend-icon="fa-user fa-lg"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 md3>
                    <v-text-field
                      label="Apellido"
                      v-model="filter.lastName"
                      prepend-icon="fa-user fa-lg"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 md3>
                    <v-text-field
                      label="Documento"
                      v-model="filter.document"
                      prepend-icon="fa-user fa-lg"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 md3>
                    <v-text-field
                      type="number"
                      label="Telefono"
                      v-model="filter.phone"
                      prepend-icon="fa-phone fa-lg"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 md3>
                    <v-text-field
                      label="Email"
                      v-model="filter.mail"
                      prepend-icon="fa-envelope-o fa-lg"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 md3>
                    <v-select
                      v-bind:items="localities"
                      v-model="filter.locality"
                      label="Select"
                      prepend-icon="fa-map-marker fa-lg"
                      autocomplete
                    ></v-select>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
              </v-form>
              <v-layout row wrap>
                <v-flex md12 offset-md8>
                  <v-btn flat color="error" @click="clearFilters">Limpiar</v-btn>
                  <v-btn color="purple darken-2" dark @click="getClientFilter">
                    Buscar
                  </v-btn>
                  <v-btn color="deep-orange darken-2" dark
                         router
                         :to="'/new-client'">
                    Nuevo
                  </v-btn>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-slide-y-transition>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs10 offset-xs1>
        <v-data-table
          v-bind:headers="headers"
          v-bind:items="clients"
          v-bind:search="search"
          v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination"
          hide-actions
          class="elevation-1">
          <template slot="headerCell" slot-scope="props">
            <v-tooltip bottom>
              <span slot="activator">
                {{ props.header.text }}
              </span>
              <span>
                {{ props.header.text }}
              </span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </template>
          <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.document }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.locality }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.state }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-left">
              <v-btn icon class="mx-0" color="primary" @click="editClient(props.item)">
                <v-icon>fa-pencil</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn icon class="mx-0" color="error">
                <v-icon>fa-trash</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </td>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
        <div class="text-xs-center pt-2">
          <v-pagination v-model="pagination.page" :length="pages"></v-pagination>
        </div>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import UrlUtils from '../../class/UrlUtils'
  import {clientBus} from '../../main'

  export default {
    mounted () {
      this.getClients()
      this.getLocalities()
    },
    data: () => ({
      clients: [],
      show: true,
      valid: false,
      localities: [],
      search: '',
      pagination: {},
      selected: [],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Nombre',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'DNI',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'calories'
        },
        {
          text: 'Localidad',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'fat'
        },
        {
          text: 'Estado',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'carbs'
        },
        {
          text: 'Acciones',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'protein'
        }
      ],
      filter: {
        name: null,
        lastName: null,
        document: null,
        phone: null,
        mail: null,
        locality: null
      }
    }),
    methods: {
      getLocalities: function () {
        axios.get(UrlUtils + '/api/localities').then((res) => {
          res.data.localities.forEach(locality => {
            this.localities.push(locality.name)
          })
        })
      },
      getClients: function () {
        axios.get(UrlUtils + '/api/client/').then((res) => {
          if (res.data.client.length > 0) {
            this.clients = res.data.client
          }
        })
      },
      getClientFilter: function () {
        axios.post(UrlUtils + '/api/client/filter', this.filter).then((res) => {
          if (res.data.clients.length > 0) {
            this.show = false
            this.clients = res.data.clients
            this.clearFilters()
          }
        })
      },
      clearFilters: function () {
        this.filter.name = null
        this.filter.lastName = null
        this.filter.document = null
        this.filter.phone = null
        this.filter.mail = null
        this.filter.locality = null
      },
      editClient: function (client) {
        clientBus.$emit('emit2', {editable: true, client: client})
        this.$router.push('/new-client')
      }
    },

    computed: {
      pages () {
        let val = 1
        if (this.clients.length > 5) {
          if (Math.trunc(this.clients.length / 5) < this.clients.length / 5) {
            val = Math.trunc(this.clients.length / 5) + 1
          } else {
            val = Math.trunc(this.clients.length / 5)
          }
        }
        return val
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

componente 2

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid grid-list-xl>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs10 offset-xs1>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title primary-title dark class="red darken-2">
            <div>
              <div class="headline white--text"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Nuevo Cliente</div>
            </div>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-form v-model="valid">
              <v-layout row wrap>
                <v-flex xs12>
                  <v-card>
                    <v-card-title primary-title dark class="purple darken-2">
                      <div>
                        <div class="headline white--text"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Cliente</div>
                      </div>
                      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                      <v-icon icon @click="show = !show" class="white--text pointer">{{ show ? 'fa-chevron-up' :
                        'fa-chevron-down' }}
                      </v-icon>

                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-slide-y-transition>
                      <v-card-text v-show="show">
                        <v-layout row wrap>
                          <v-flex xs12 md4>
                            <v-text-field
                              label="Nombre"
                              v-model="client.name"
                              prepend-icon="fa-user-circle-o fa-lg"
                            ></v-text-field>
                          </v-flex>
                          <v-flex xs12 md4>
                            <v-text-field
                              label="Apellido"
                              v-model="client.lastName"
                              prepend-icon="fa-user-circle-o fa-lg"
                            ></v-text-field>
                          </v-flex>
                          <v-flex xs12 md4>
                            <v-text-field
                              type="number"
                              min="0"
                              label="Documento"
                              v-model="client.document"
                              prepend-icon="fa-book fa-lg"
                            ></v-text-field>
                          </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                      </v-card-text>
                    </v-slide-y-transition>
                  </v-card>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
              <br>
              <v-layout row wrap>
                <v-flex xs12>
                  <v-card>
                    <v-card-title primary-title dark class="purple darken-2">
                      <div>
                        <div class="headline white--text"><i class="fa fa-map-o"></i> Direccion</div>
                      </div>
                      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                      <v-icon icon @click="showLocation = !showLocation" class="white--text pointer">{{ showLocation ?
                        'fa-chevron-up' :
                        'fa-chevron-down' }}
                      </v-icon>

                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-slide-y-transition>
                      <v-card-text v-show="showLocation">
                        <v-form v-model="valid">
                          <v-layout row wrap>
                            <v-flex xs12 md2>
                              <v-text-field
                                type="text"
                                label="Calle"
                                v-model="client.street"
                                prepend-icon="fa-map-signs fa-lg"
                              ></v-text-field>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs12 md2>
                              <v-text-field
                                type="number"
                                label="Número"
                                v-model="client.number"
                                prepend-icon="fa-hashtag fa-lg"
                              ></v-text-field>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs12 md2>
                              <v-text-field
                                type="text"
                                label="Barrio"
                                v-model="client.district"
                                prepend-icon="fa-street-view fa-lg"
                              ></v-text-field>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs12 md3>
                              <v-select
                                v-bind:items="departamentsSelect"
                                prepend-icon="fa-map-marker fa-lg"
                                v-model="departament"
                                label="Departamento"
                                autocomplete
                              ></v-select>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs12 md3>
                              <v-select
                                v-bind:items="localitySelect"
                                prepend-icon="fa-map-marker fa-lg"
                                v-model="client.locality"
                                label="Localidades"
                                autocomplete
                              ></v-select>
                            </v-flex>
                          </v-layout>
                        </v-form>
                      </v-card-text>
                    </v-slide-y-transition>
                  </v-card>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
              <br>
              <v-layout row wrap>
                <v-flex xs12>
                  <v-card>
                    <v-card-title primary-title dark class="purple darken-2">
                      <div>
                        <div class="headline white--text"><i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i> Contacto</div>
                      </div>
                      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                      <v-icon icon @click="showContacto = !showContacto" class="white--text pointer">{{ showContacto ?
                        'fa-chevron-up' :
                        'fa-chevron-down' }}
                      </v-icon>

                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-slide-y-transition>
                      <v-card-text v-show="showContacto">
                        <v-form v-model="valid">
                          <v-layout row wrap>
                            <v-flex xs12 md3>
                              <v-text-field
                                type="number"
                                label="Número de telefono"
                                v-model="client.phone"
                                prepend-icon="fa-phone fa-lg"
                              ></v-text-field>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs12 md3>
                              <v-select
                                v-bind:items="lines"
                                v-model="client.line"
                                label="Linea"
                                prepend-icon="fa-volume-control-phone fa-lg"
                                single-line
                                bottom
                              ></v-select>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs12 md1>
                              <v-layout row>
                                <v-flex xs1 md2>
                                  <br>
                                  <v-icon class="green--text">fa-whatsapp fa-lg</v-icon>
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 md10>
                                  <br>
                                  <v-switch :label="client.wpp ? 'Si' : 'No'"
                                            v-model="client.wpp"
                                            color="success"
                                  ></v-switch>
                                </v-flex>
                              </v-layout>
                            </v-flex>
                            <v-flex xs12 md5>
                              <v-text-field
                                type="mail"
                                label="E-mail"
                                v-model="client.mail"
                                prepend-icon="fa-envelope-o fa-lg"
                              ></v-text-field>
                              {{client.mail}}
                            </v-flex>
                          </v-layout>
                        </v-form>
                      </v-card-text>
                    </v-slide-y-transition>
                  </v-card>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>

            </v-form>
            <v-flex xs2 offset-xs10>
              <v-btn flat color="error">Cancelar</v-btn>
              <v-btn v-if="!editable" color="purple darken-2" dark 
    @click="saveClient">
                Guardar
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn v-else color="purple darken-2" dark @click="saveClient">
                Actializar
              </v-btn>
            </v-flex>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import UrlUtils from '../../class/UrlUtils'
  import {clientBus} from '../../main'

  export default {
    name: 'new-client',
    mounted () {
      this.getDepataments()
      this.getLocalities()
    },
    data: () => ({
      editable: false,
      valid: true,
      departaments: [],
      departamentsSelect: [],
      localitySelect: [],
      show: true,
      showContacto: true,
      showLocation: true,
      lines: ['Personal',
        'Claro',
        'Movistar',
        'Fijo'],
      departament: null,
      client: {
        _id: null,
        __v: null,
        name: null,
        lastName: null,
        document: null,
        phone: null,
        line: null,
        mail: null,
        wpp: false,
        street: null,
        number: null,
        district: null,
        locality: null,
        state: 'Activo'
      }
    }),
    methods: {
      getDepataments: function () {
        axios.get(UrlUtils + '/api/departaments').then((res) => {
          this.departaments = res.data.departaments
          res.data.departaments.forEach(departament => {
            this.departamentsSelect.push(departament.name)
          })
        })
      },
      getLocalities: function () {
        axios.get(UrlUtils + '/api/localities').then((res) => {
          res.data.localities.forEach(locality => {
            this.localitySelect.push(locality.name)
          })
        })
      },
      getLocalitiesFilters: function () {
        axios.get(UrlUtils + '/api/localities/' + this.departament).then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data.localities)
          this.localitySelect = []
          res.data.localities.forEach(locality => {
            this.localitySelect.push(locality.name)
          })
        })
      },
      saveClient: function () {
        axios.post(UrlUtils + '/api/client', this.client).then((res) => {
          console.log(res)
          this.$router.push('/search-client')
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }
    },
    created () {
      clientBus.$on('emit2', (clientOption) => {
        console.log('Created', clientOption.editable)
        this.editable = clientOption.editable
        if (clientOption.editable) {
          console.log('clientBus', clientOption.client)
          // this.client = clientOption.client
          this.client.mail = clientOption.client.mail
          console.log('client', this.client)
        }
      })
    },
    watch: {
      departament: function (event) {
        this.getLocalitiesFilters()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Haz intentado esto?  `window.bus = new Vue({}); `

Comment: Gracias pero ya resolví esto hace mucho tiempo utilizando Vuex

Comment: Pues no estaría mal que compartas la solución como una respuesta y la marques como respondida. Además ganas puntos.